# key bases on ubuntu - what's wrong with them

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I've got key database (called default) on my ubuntu and it still asks me about password that I don't know. How can I turn it off or just get pass ?

Comment: Are you talking about the Ubuntu keyring? If you've forgotten the password (which can be different from your login password) you may have to delete the default keyring and create a new one. I'm not sure there is a way to recover that without brute force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running gnome and you just want to delete the key ring and start over, you could just delete it.

WARNING THIS WILL DELETE YOUR KEYRING AND ALL THE CONTENTS!

```
rm ~/.gnome2/keyrings/login.keyring
```

Comment: You lead me to the better way but I had to remove defualt.keyring